# How to deploy Apache Nifi on a k8s pod?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-nifi

I am using K8S with minikube. I have deployed zookepers for Apache Nifi with:

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/application/zookeeper/zookeeper.yaml
```

With `kubectl get pods` I see :

```
NAME   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
zk-0   1/1     Running   0          128m
zk-1   0/1     Pending   0          128m
```

Now I try to deploy nifi on a pod with a old yaml file I saw on the internet:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Service             #+
apiVersion: v1            #+
metadata:                 #+
  name: nifi-service     #+
spec:                     #+
  selector:               #+
    app: nifi            #+
  ports:                  #+
  - protocol: TCP         #+
    targetPort: 8080     #+
    port: 8080              #+
    name: ui            #+
  - protocol: TCP         #+
    targetPort: 9088     #+
    port: 9088              #+
    name: node-protocol-port            #+
  - protocol: TCP         #+
    targetPort: 8888     #+
    port: 8888              #+
    name: s2s            #+
  type: LoadBalancer      #+
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: nifi
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nifi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nifi
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
      - name: nifi-container
        image: sunmanregistry.azurecr.io/nifi:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
        - containerPort: 22
          name: ssh
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: ".5"
            memory: "6Gi"
          limits:
            cpu: "1"
        env:
        - name: VERSION
          value: "1.9"
        - name: NIFI_CLUSTER_IS_NODE
          value: "true"
        - name: NIFI_CLUSTER_NODE_PROTOCOL_PORT
          value: "9088"
        - name: NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_CANDIDATES
          value: "1"
        - name: NIFI_ZK_CONNECT_STRING
          value: "zk-0.zk-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:2181,zk-1.zk-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:2181,zk-2.zk-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:2181"
```

But I don't know where is the image I have to use and next what steps and in what order I have to enter commands in terminal.

I see no recent tutorials on the internet to learn how to deploy nifi on k8s.

Can someone explain to me how to deploy nifi well on a k8s pod and what is the best method ?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, bud deployment-related, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable question for the [mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@nifi.apache.org) or the [slack channel](https://apachenifi.slack.com/) ([invite-link](https://join.slack.com/t/apachenifi/shared_invite/zt-11njbtkdx-ZRU8FKYSWoEHRJetidy0zA)).